# Is there a difference when persisting entity via child or parent entity in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

Is there a difference in hibernate performance/optimization when persisting data from child vs. parent entity?

More precisely, let's say we have a @OneToOne mapping between AccountEntity and TokenEntity like shown below:

```
@Entity("Accounts)
class AccountEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private TokenEntity token;

  void setToken(TokenEntity value) {
    if (value == null) {
      if (token != null) token.account = null;
    } else value.account = this;

    token = value;
  }

  // rest omitted for brevity
}

@Entity("Tokens")
class TokenEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @MapsId
  private AccountEntity account;

  // rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Let's say we would like to assign a token entity to account and persist it. Doing so via TokenRepository save method will generate 1 insert statement into Tokens table, while doing so via AccountRepository update method will generate 1 insert into Tokens table and 1 update for AccountEntity.

Is there a performance difference when persisting data based on their relation (parent or child)?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see is the cascade defined, which in the case of the token will not produce additional statement.